# Submodule of a semisimple module is semisimple .

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have a doubt in proving the above statement . 
Lets say that $M$ a semisimple module , then consider $P  \subset N$ , $P$ and $N$ are two sub-modules of $M$ .

now since $M$ is a semisimple module , then there exists $P'$ and $N'$ such that the direct sum of $P, P'$ is $M$ and $N, N'$ is $M$.

$N= M\cap N$ , now can i write $M$ as just $P+P'$ , i mean when can i write just sum in place of direct sum .

EDIT

My notes say 
$N= M\cap N =(P+P') \cap N = P+(P' \cap N) $ and $P\cap (P' \cap N) = \{0\}$ 
I know that $M$ is a direct sum of $P$ and $P'$ but my notes just igonres the direct sum sign . 
I don't understand whats going on .

Comment: I cannot tell what you are asking, really. WHat role do $N$ and $N'$ play in all this?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : i will do some edit .

Comment: Your edit did not help much... My mind reading maching suggests the following, though: if you know that $M=A\oplus B$, in particular you know that $M=A+B$, simply by the definition of what a direct sum is.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : that means the direct sum and sum are not different at all .

Comment: No, it does not mean that. As I wrote, if you know that $M=A\oplus B$ then you know that $M=A+B$. *I did not say the converse implication holds* (and it doesn't)

Comment: Just look up the meaning of what it means that $M=A\oplus B$, and check for yourself that it implies that $M=A+B$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : i got it . thanks

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way to do this is based on the fact that

> a module is semisimple if it is a **sum** of simple submodules.

If $M$ is semisimple, and $N\subseteq M$ is a submodule, then it is easy to check that $N$ is the sum of all the simple submodules of $M$ it contains, and therefore it is semisimple.

Comment: Would you please add some details on "$N$ is the sum of simple submodules of $M$ it contains"? I do not find it trivial.

Comment: Well, I know that an equivalent definition for a module $M$ semisimple module is "$M$ is the sum of all of its simple submodules." But I got stuck on the inference "$N$ is a submodule of the semisimple module $M$ $\overset{?}{\implies}$ $N$ is the sum of all of the simple submodule of $M$ contained in $N$".  Can you explain this inference? (Many textbooks leave "Submodules of semisimple modules are semisimple" as exercise. I understand the proof using the direct sum definition. But I still wonder how this proof works.)

Comment: I now understand it. This is a nice proof.

Comment: However, if you mean using the fact $K\cap Soc\ M=Soc\ K$ (corollary 9.9), then I think there is some gap and can not be summarized by "easy to check".

Answer (score 6):

There are a few equivalent ways to define a semisimple module and it would be helpful to know exactly which formulation you are using.  One possible formulation is the following:

**Definition.** *A module $M$ is* semisimple *if every submodule of $M$ is a direct summand of $M$.*

Then to prove that every submodule of $M$ is semisimple let $N \subseteq M$ be a submodule and assume $P \subseteq N$ is a submodule of $N$.  Write $M = N \oplus N' = P \oplus P'$ for some $N'$ and $P'$.  What we need is to find $Q$ such that $N = P \oplus Q$.

Let $Q = P' \cap N$.  This is a submodule of $N$ so we need to show that $N = P + Q$ and $P \cap Q = 0$.  For the first let $n \in N$.  Then $n \in M$ so $n = a + b$ for some uniquely determined $a \in P$ and $b \in P'$.  As $P \subseteq N$ we have $n, a \in N$ therefore $b \in N$ therefore $b \in Q$.  This gives $n \in P + Q$ and consequently $N = P + Q$.

For the second assume $n \in P \cap Q$.  Then $n \in Q = P' \cap N$ so $n \in P'$.  But $n \in P$ and $n \in P'$ imply $n = 0$.  Hence $P \cap Q = 0$.

Comment: Yes , this is more or less what i am following . My question is when can a person write just 'sum' instead of 'direct sum' ?

Comment: When $A$ and $B$ are submodules of the same module $M$.

Comment: @Theorem Adding this because I'm speculating Theorem meant something else with that first comment. If $A$ and $B$ are submodules of $M$ and $A\oplus B=M$ is an (internal) direct sum, you can also write $A+B=M$. So, every (internal) direct sum equal to $M$ is also a sum equal to $M$, but the converse is not true. If $C+D=M$, the sum is not direct unless $C\cap D=\{0\}$. The following can be proven: a module is a sum of simple submodules iff it is a *direct* sum of simple submodules.